# Does Matthew 5:44 apply only to "you" (ὑμᾶς) or also to Jesus?

Tags: matthew, commandments-of-jesus

Does the commandment in **Matthew 5:44** apply **only to "you" (ὑμᾶς)** [or] also to Jesus?

[Matthew 5:44](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205%3A44&version=NKJV) [NKJV]

> "But I say to you, love your enemies, bless those who curse you, do good to those who hate you, and pray for those who spitefully use you and persecute you"

Answer (score 2):

Matthew 5:44 [NKJV]

> "But I say to you, love your enemies, bless those who curse you, do good to those who hate you, and pray for those who spitefully use you and persecute you"

Jesus had certainly practised that in Luke 23:34

> Then Jesus said, "Father, forgive them, for they do not know what they are doing." And they divided up His garments by casting lots.

Judas the betrayer spitefully used Jesus and persecuted Jesus.
Concerning Judas, Jesus said in John 17:12

> While I was with them, I protected them and kept them safe by that name you gave me. None has been lost **except the one doomed to destruction** so that Scripture would be fulfilled.

Jesus did not pray for Judas to be delivered from destruction.

As believers, we have our responsibilities and God has his. Paul explained it well in
Romans 12:

> 17 Do not repay anyone evil for evil. Be careful to do what is right in the eyes of everyone. 18If it is possible, as far as it depends on you, live at peace with everyone. 19Do not take revenge, my dear friends, but leave room for **God’s wrath**, for it is written: “It is mine to avenge; I will repay,” says the Lord. 20On the contrary:
>
> “If your enemy is hungry, feed him;
> if he is thirsty, give him something to drink.
> In doing this, you will heap burning coals on his head.”
> 21Do not be overcome by evil, but overcome evil with good.

Comment: Interesting Response - “Jesus did not pray for Judas to be delivered from destruction.”

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote the lager passage of Matt 5:38-48 -

> **38** **You** have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye and tooth for tooth.’ **39** But I tell **you** not to resist an evil person. If
> someone slaps **you** on your right cheek, turn to him the other also;
> **40** if someone wants to sue **you** and take your tunic, let him have **your** cloak as well; **41** and if someone forces **you** to
> go one mile, go with him two miles. **42** Give to the one who asks
> **you**, and do not turn away from the one who wants to borrow from **you**.
>
> **43** **You** have heard that it was said, ‘Love **your** neighbor’ and ‘Hate **your** enemy.’ 44But I tell **you**, love **your** enemies
> and pray for those who persecute **you**, **45** that **you** may be
> sons of **your** Father in heaven. He causes His sun to rise on the
> evil and the good, and sends rain on the righteous and the
> unrighteous. **46** If **you** love those who love **you**, what
> reward will **you** get? Do not even tax collectors do the same?
> **47** And if **you** greet only **your** brothers, what are **you** doing more than others? Do not even Gentiles do the same?
>
> **48** Be perfect, therefore, as **your** heavenly Father is perfect.

It appears quite obvious that Jesus is giving a series of rules about how we should love our enemies.  The entire passage is about the behavior of Jesus' followers/disciples.

Therefore, the passage applies to "you" or "us" as Jesus' followers.  However, I note the important principle contained 1 John 4:16, 19

> And we have come to know and believe the love that God has for us. God
> is love; whoever abides in love abides in God, and God in him. ... We
> love because He first loved us.

Thus, in loving our enemies, we follow Jesus' example.